# Flutter Web - failed to compile application

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I want to build a new web application with flutter. For this purpose I followed the instructions on the flutter website (https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web). Everything works as described and i also got another web app running.
After creating the default app i want to run it with the command 'flutter run -d chrome' but this fails and i get following error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/compiler/frontend/kernel_translation_helper.cc: 2099: error: Unexpected tag 34 (LogicalExpression) in ?, expected a procedure, a constructor or a function node
version=2.12.3 (stable) (Wed Apr 14 11:02:39 2021 +0200) on "windows_x64"
pid=7912, thread=20068, isolate_group=main(00000164F90EDC90), isolate=main(00000164F911A7D0)
isolate_instructions=164fc240000, vm_instructions=7ff61d99f960
  pc 0x00007ff61db20fb2 fp 0x0000004bf60fce30 Unknown symbol
-- End of DumpStackTrace
[exit     : sp(0) fp(0x4bf60fec28) pc(0)]
[stub     : sp(0x4bf60fec38) fp(0x4bf60fec78) pc(0x164fcf02e23)]        
[dart     : sp(0x4bf60fec88) fp(0x4bf60fece8) pc(0x164fc3dcadb) package:args/src/parser.dart_Parser_parseLongOption ]
[dart     : sp(0x4bf60fecf8) fp(0x4bf60fed70) pc(0x164fc3df7ba) package:args/src/parser.dart_Parser_parse ]
[dart     : sp(0x4bf60fed80) fp(0x4bf60feda8) pc(0x164fc3e161e) package:args/src/arg_parser.dart_ArgParser_parse ]
[dart     : sp(0x4bf60fedb8) fp(0x4bf60fee38) pc(0x164fc7c42d6) package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart_::_starter__async_op ]
[dart     : sp(0x4bf60fee48) fp(0x4bf60feed0) pc(0x164fc7ad330) package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart_::_starter ]
[dart     : sp(0x4bf60feee0) fp(0x4bf60fef58) pc(0x164fca33212) file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/flutter/flutter_frontend_server/bin/starter.dart_::_main__async_op ]
[dart     : sp(0x4bf60fef68) fp(0x4bf60fef90) pc(0x164fca337de) file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/flutter/flutter_frontend_server/bin/starter.dart_::_main ]
[dart     : sp(0x4bf60fefa0) fp(0x4bf60fefc0) pc(0x164fca338cc) file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/flutter/flutter_frontend_server/bin/starter.dart_::_main_main ]
[dart     : sp(0x4bf60fefd0) fp(0x4bf60ff020) pc(0x164fc3cf67f) dart:core__Closure@0150898_dyn_call ]
[dart     : sp(0x4bf60ff030) fp(0x4bf60ff058) pc(0x164fc5580c8) dart:isolate_::__delayEntrypointInvocation@1026248_<anonymous closure> ]
[dart     : sp(0x4bf60ff068) fp(0x4bf60ff0b8) pc(0x164fc3cf67f) dart:core__Closure@0150898_dyn_call ]
[dart     : sp(0x4bf60ff0c8) fp(0x4bf60ff0f0) pc(0x164fca9c728) dart:isolate__RawReceivePortImpl@1026248__handleMessage@1026248 ]
[entry    : sp(0x4bf60ff100) fp(0x4bf60ff218) pc(0x164fcf02308)]        
the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...           1.289ms
Failed to compile application.
```

this is the output from flutter doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.900], locale de-DE)
    • Flutter version 2.0.5 at C:\Users\rfobo\flutter
    • Framework revision adc687823a (10 days ago), 2021-04-16 09:40:20 -0700
    • Engine revision b09f014e96
    • Dart version 2.12.3

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\rfobo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.55.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\rfobo\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.21.0

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 90.0.4430.85
    • Edge (web)   • edge   • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 89.0.774.68

• No issues found!
```

As described in the error message there's some 'unexpected tag' in the kernel_translation_helper.cc but i'm unable to open this file...

Is there any logical reason how this can occur? I recently updated Android Studio, maybe this broke something?

Comment: Try `flutter clean` and if it doesn't solve the issue, run `flutter create .` inside the project folder. This will recreate the web folder and should run as expected. I don't see any logical error here as per the error log.

Comment: both solutions don't work unfortunately, i'll get the same error as before